# How to add an element to the jquery.shapeshift grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append and element to the grid created by jquery.shapeshift. The [documentation](https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift/wiki/2.0-api-documentation) says to trigger a rearrange once the element is added. I've tried but I get nothing. What am I doing wrong? See the example http://jsfiddle.net/LNysC/1307/

```
$(".container").shapeshift({
    minColumns: 3
});


$("a").click(function(){

    $(".container").append("<div></div>");
    $(".container").trigger("ss-event-arrange");

});
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The div you added that way is not recognized by the container as a child yet so you should tell the container that the div you added is a child to be treated like so. 
I know there should be another way to do it, but try reshapeing the container by calling `$(".container").shapeshift()` again, for example:

```
$(".container").shapeshift({
    minColumns: 3
});


$("a").click(function(){

    $(".container").append("<div></div>");

    $(".container").shapeshift();
});
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/LNysC/1501/